# Collapse expander inside ItemsControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am showing a list of expander items inside a ItemsControl and bind a list of items to it. 
The xaml structure i am following is

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" >            
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander ExpandDirection="Down" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ExpanderItemStyle}" >
                <Expander.Header>
                    <BulletDecorator>
                    //Expander header by default its collapsed 
                    <Label Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ChapterHeadStyle}"  Content="{Binding name}"></Label>                                         
                    </BulletDecorator>
                </Expander.Header>
                <StackPanel> // Expander body want to collapse it when some some other items of ItemsControl is expanded 
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Can i make the expander content colpased automatically when some other items in the ItemsControl is selcted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `ItemsControl` with `ListBox` an bind `IsExpanded` property of `Expander` to `IsSelected` property of `ListBoxItem`. (see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a2988ae8-e7b8-4a62-a34f-b851aaf13886/windows-presentation-foundation-faq?forum=wpf#expander_list)

You can also bind `IsExpanded` to some viewmodel property and take it from there. The same result can be achieved via wpf behaviours.

To answer your question: no, there is no "automatic" way to collapse other expanders.

Comment: IsExpanded="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem, Mode=FindAncestor}}"   This way it worked for me  Thanks for help :)